# Saving and retrieving model name

Tags: python, json, keras, save

I'm using Keras to train my model and this is how I specify its name:

```
model = Sequential()
model.name = 'NameOfMyModel'
[...]
```

Afterwards I save it to the disk as follows:

```
model_json = model.to_json()
with open(pathToModel+".json","w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

model.save_weights(pathToModel+'.h5')
```

Later, I load it again with the following code:

```
json_file = open(path+'.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()

loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
loaded_model.load_weights(path+".h5")
```

I would like to retrieve the name of my model again from the loaded model by doing:

```
modelName = loaded_model.name
```

However, instead of the string `'NameOfMyModel'`, the string `'sequential_1'` is returned. What am I missing here?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. It shows me `'NameOfMyModel'` after loading the model.

Comment: Hum... strange. What Keras version are you using?

Comment: My Keras version is 2.2.4.

Comment: Of course, I also train my model before saving it to the disk, which is not obvious from the code above. Maybe the problem is introduced by training the model?

Comment: No. It shows me the correct name even if I train it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, by upgrading Keras (from version 2.2.0 to 2.2.4) the issue was resolved.